# What is the vocal technique for Adrien's (Northlane) Low Scream?

Tags: voice

I have been told by people that Adrien from Northlane's low screams are growls, but I am not convinced. I have linked below a video with the particular scream I would like to know the name of, and how to accomplish a similar sound.

at time 3:34

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're talking about the hallowed [Death Growl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_growl).  And here's a chap [demonstrating how to achieve the technique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFLC0RQ6xAQ).

Finally, [here's a top 10 from YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVflR3TwYDY) (NSFW), just to confirm we're talking about the same technique.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Morris! However I am finding mixed results. My vocal trainer originally would've agreed with you, but now is convinced it is a low fry scream

Comment: I wouldn't fret over the semantics. As there are multiple terms and phrases to explain the technique you're after, I think you'll just have to investigate further to find the right sound/method/approach for you. [Vocal Fry on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_fry_register#In_singing)